# installing PHP on Apache 2.2 on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, apache2

I had my Apache 2.2 installed on windows. Now I just finished installing PHP on the Apache server. As the instruction says, I need to edit the httpd.conf of my Apache and add:

```
# 
LoadModule php5_module "G:\Program Files\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

PHPIniDir "G:\Program Files\PHP"
```

I made sure the directory is correct. Then I restart my server again. I have a hello.php file in my htdocs. And I navigate to localhost:8080/hello.php and it says server not found, however when I do index.html. It display's the html correctly on the htdocs folder.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried to debug this by trying to execute hello.php from the command line by executing G:\Program Files\PHP\php-cgi hello.php, but then it says:

'G:\Program is not recognized as internal or external command.....

Comment: btw did you restart your server after the edit?

Comment: What are you editing your config file with?  I was helping someone once where what I thought were regular double quotes were actually left quotes and right quotes, and that messed everything up.  Also, you might try regular slashes instead of back slashes in the path.  Older Apache had troubles with that... I haven't messed with 2.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some this like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) its easy to configuration.

Comment: I should have remembered this. I use XAMPP in my mac

Comment: That's like bringing a rusty tank to a fist fight.

Comment: I did uninstall the apached and PHP I had and now install it with XAMPP. Now when I start the apache server it directly quits

Comment: ok..fixed it, just changed the port in the config file to 8080.. I don't know what's the issue with port 80