# Configuring Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.x on Windows 8

Tags: php, apache, windows-8, apache2.2

I have Windows 8 64 bit,
I downloaded Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.53 Thread Safe
and put them in "D:/Server" folder.

D:\Server\Apache2

D:\Server\php

I copied the file "php.ini-production" in D:\Server\php and named it php.ini ; The file php5apache2_4.dll exist in D:/Server/php

Then I edit "D:\Server\Apache2\conf\httpd.txt":

```
...
LoadModule php5_module "D:/Server/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
...
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
...
PHPIniDir "D:/Server/php"
```

Then I try to restart Apache 2.2 but it pop up en Error window: "The requested operation has failed"
(If I omit the first and the thirs declerations, it does restart...)

I also tried PHP 5.2.17 that has php5apache2_2.dll file, and it doesn't work..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [installing PHP on Apache 2.2 on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236805/installing-php-on-apache-2-2-on-windows-7)

Comment: have you checked your php.ini file? also what is the full error when you run `D:\Server\Apache2\bin\httpd -k start` from command prompt (use administrative command prompt)

Comment: Thank you very much bansi. didn't know you can see the full error. this command helped a lot (stupid syntax error)!

Comment: It works with PHP 5.2.17 that has php5apache2_2.dll

Answer (score 1):

Use AddHandler instead of AddType... Also, windows-style slashes work fine for paths.

E.g. my httpd.conf contains following:

```
PHPIniDir "C:\php\"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\php\php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```